# Stuck in Starting arch 250.##

Tags: boot, x11, drivers, usb-drive, graphics

I have a USB stick with Arch Linux installed on it. The USB stick works well on a school PC and my gaming PC, but gets stuck in "Starting arch version 250.##" every time I try to boot it up on my home PC.

My guess is this has something to do with video drivers as the school PC this works on uses integrated Intel graphics and my gaming PC has both integrated Intel and external Nvidia graphics. The home PC this does not work on uses only external Nvidia graphics.

The Arch USB runs X11 and KDE Plasma.

Things I have tried:

- `startx` was not found, startplasma-x11 existed, but returned `$DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to X server`
- I probably should try using `nomodeset`, but I don't know how to pass these weird parameters or whatever they are.
- `systemctl start sddm` ran and started SDDM and it was visible in htop, but nothing displayed on the screen.

I am able to login to other TTYs, I can boot the USB from my gaming PC and I have a live Manjaro XFCE USB for troubleshooting if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, that was an easy fix. I had two files blacklisting nouveau and nvidia in `/usr/lib/modprobe.d/` so I deleted them. I also removed optimus-manager as I don't need this USB to work for optimus PCs.

( "Cannot accept your own answer in 2 days", guess we'll wait )